# command to replace particular sub string and cast it as string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am working on Linux, and I have the strings as below:

```
SELECT  concat_ws("|",max(date_column),substr(abc,1,9)) key
SELECT  concat_ws("|",xyz_date_column,abc) key
```

I need a `sed` command to get the outputs as shown below, to CAST the dynamic date columns as a string: i need to CAST only those columns that come within concat_ws function. everything after concat_ws("|", is different for each file

```
SELECT  concat_ws("|",(CAST (max(date_column) as string)),substr(abc,1,9)) key,
SELECT  concat_ws("|",(CAST (xyz_date_column) as string),abc) key
```

I tried this command but did not get the expected output:

```
sed -e 's/concat_ws(\([^\)]*\))/concat_ws(CAST(\1 as string))/g'
```

Comment: Is there a possible way to generalize this? if there is **a date column anywhere within the "concat_ws" function** it should be cast as string. The name of the date column is known as `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
sed -E 's/(concat_ws\("\|",[[:space:]]*)([^,]*),/\1(\2),/;
        s/(concat_ws\("\|",[[:space:]]*)([^,]*),/\1(CAST (\2 as string)),/' infile
```

first part is surrounding *data_column* part with extra parentheses;
second part adding into *CAST*.

Output:

```
SELECT  concat_ws("|",(CAST ((max(date_column)) as string)),substr(abc,1,9)) key
SELECT  concat_ws("|",(CAST ((xyz_date_column) as string)),abc) key
```

Comment: Is there a possible way to generalize this? if there is a **date column anywhere within the "concat_ws" function** it should be cast as string. **The name of the date column is known as `timestamp`**. I just came across this scenario..